# why the result of '1' == u'1' in python2 is True?

Tags: python, string, unicode

I use python2.7 in Linux. From https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html. I find that python use one byte for each alphabet in `str`, while it uses 4 bytes in Unicode string. So why I get `True` after I input `'1' == u'1'`.

A similar truth in python2:

```
    In [1]: a = {}
    In [2]: a['1'] = 1
    In [3]: a[u'1']
    Out[3]: 1
```

Comment: Object equality does not generally require equal types in Python.

Comment: There's an implict encoding and decoding in Python 2. More at: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html

Answer (score 3):

> UTF-8 is capable of encoding all 1,112,064 valid character code points in Unicode using **one to four** one-byte (8-bit) code units. Code points with lower numerical values, which tend to occur more frequently, are encoded using fewer bytes. It was designed for backward compatibility with ASCII: the first 128 characters of Unicode, which correspond one-to-one with ASCII, are encoded using a single byte with the same binary value as ASCII, so that **valid ASCII text is valid UTF-8-encoded Unicode** as well.

You can see an example of this:

```
>>> a = u'1'
>>> a.encode('utf-8')
'1'
>>> b = u'ツ'
>>> b.encode('utf-8')
'\xe3\x83\x84'
```